# jQuery - Transfer characters from one list to another

Tags: jquery, foreach, each

I have 2 list with characters. I'm trying to make the old characters list updated with the new characters names in the li and html based on the data attribute value. when the Change List is clicked, so the final outcome looks like this:

```
//BEFORE
<ul id="new_characters">
<li id="peter"><div data="character1" class="character">Peter Griffin</div></li>
<li id="joe"><div data="character2" class="character">Joe Swanson</div></li>
</ul>

<ul id="old_characters">
<li id="glenn"><span data="character1" class="character">Glenn Quagmire</span></li>
<li id="louis"><span data="character2" class="character">Loius Griffin</span></li>
</ul>

<span id="change">Change List</span>

//AFTER
<ul id="old_characters"> //only this list should change on #change click
<li id="peter"><span data="character1" class="character">Peter Griffin</span></li>
<li id="joe"><span data="character2" class="character">Joe Swanson</span></li>
</ul>
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wXnSZ/

Comment: Do you want to replace the old characters list with the new characters list, or append the new characters to the old characters list?

Comment: @j08691 I want to overwrite the li id and html names of the old list with the ones from the new list based on the matching data value.

Comment: OK, in my answer below I gave you solutions to both possibilities. I'll add a jsFiddle for the overwrite code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#change').click(function(){
    $('.character', '#new_characters').each(function(index, item){
        $(".character[data='"+$(item).attr('data')+"']", "#old_characters").text($(item).text());
    });    
});​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/wXnSZ/1/)

To replace the ID aswell, but keep the spans:

```
$('#change').click(function(){
    $('.character', '#new_characters').each(function(index, item){
        $(".character[data='"+$(item).attr('data')+"']", "#old_characters").text($(item).text()).parent().attr('id', $(item).parent().attr('id'));
    });    
});​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/wXnSZ/6/)

or to change the complete html of each li in old_characters based on the data attribute:

```
$('#change').click(function(){
    $('.character', '#new_characters').each(function(index, item){
        $(".character[data='"+$(item).attr('data')+"']", "#old_characters").replaceWith($(item).clone());
    });    
});​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/wXnSZ/3/)

or to just put the HTML of new_characters into old_characters:

```
$('#change').click(function(){
   $("#old_characters").html($('#new_characters').html());
});​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/wXnSZ/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Here are two possibilities:

1) Append new characters to old characters list:

```
$('#change').click(function() {
    $('#old_characters').append($('#new_characters').contents());
    $('#new_characters').remove();
});​
```

2) Replace old characters with new characters:

```
$('#change').click(function() {
    $('#old_characters').contents().replaceWith($('#new_characters').contents());
});​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/wXnSZ/2/)** for solution #2.